# Simple interface for getting HTML content in Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, url, boost-asio

There are a lot of examples how to make HTTP request to a server and get reply via boost.asio library. However, I couldn't find a good example of simple interface and wondering, if I need to implement it myself.

For instance, if I need to get content of *http://www.foo.bar/path/to/default.html*, is there any way to get a content without validating URL, making HTTP request and parsing server answer?

Basically, I am looking for something like this:

```
std::string str = boost::asio::get_content("http://www.foo.bar/path/to/default.html");
std::cout << str;

#
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    Simple HTML page!
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

There are couple of things that I would like to avoid using boost.asio.

- Avoid parsing and validating URL.
- Manually creating HTTP request.
- Cutting HTTP response from HTML page content.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like there is no simple interface in boost.asio library itself, however, I found urdl (http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html) library from the owner of boost.asio library, that allows to make such things.

Answer (score 10):

Since then, there is a newcomer; the [C++ Network Library: cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/) as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2251483/171711).

You wanted to use asio. I suppose you fancied the portability and the ease of use of this lib, so [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/) will be a great choice in that case. It is based on same principles as boost and its authors aim at integrating it into boost.

It is pretty simple to use:

```
http::client client;
/*<< Creates a request using a URI supplied on the command line. >>*/
http::client::request request("http://www.foo.bar/path/to/default.html");
/*<< Gets a response from the HTTP server. >>*/
http::client::response response = client.get(request);
/*<< Prints the response body to the console. >>*/
std::cout << body(response) << std::endl;
```

I haven't tried this one but it seems to be possible to do exactly what you need:

```
cout << body(client().get(client::request("http://www.foo.bar/path/to/default.html")));
```

This question was asked a long time ago, sorry for digging it out of its grave.

Comment: i agree it's probably the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to implement these functions yourself.  Boost.Asio is a socket library primarily, that can be used to implement various protocols.  But there's no built-in convenience functions just for some specific protocol like HTTP or SMTP.  (Well, actually there's built in DNS resolution, but that's about it.)

However, the Boost.Asio source code comes with pre-made examples of an HTTP client/server, so you can easily start with that.

Answer (score 3):

boost.asio is powerful and sophisticated, but probably overkill for this.

Have you looked at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)?

Answer (score 3):

From the person who wrote boost.asio

http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/urdl/getting_started/integrating_with_boost_asio.html

boost::urdl is a library for reading urls into strings easily.

Comment: Given that Boost.Asio is the prototype for Network TS, integration with it is crucial, so I think this answer should be the standard one.

Answer (score 2):

boost.asio doesn't provide such functionality. But I believe there are a number of libraries that do. See [POCO libraries](http://pocoproject.org/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, [Boost.Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html) made an appearance, which wraps Boost.Asio to provide a simpler interface (not only) for [HTTP GET](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/quick_start/http_client.html).