# How to read text from internet with C++

Tags: c++, text, get, network-programming

I trying get text data from internet with C++ but I couldn't find anything useful.

like python;

```
import urllib
data = urllib.urlopen("examplesite.com/data.txt").read()
```

Comment: Step one in C++ is, almost always, finding a suitable library. Which ones have you tried? Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763816/simple-interface-for-getting-html-content-in-boost-asio) come close to answering?

Comment: I could not find any documentation about libcurl or boost, I tried with InternetOpenUrl, InternetReadFile etc but i was not succesful

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time believing that. There is a ton of documentation on both of those, they're extremely popular libraries. This is like being unable to find Google with Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).  It is a C library, with [C++ bindings](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/).

The libcurl website includes [a collection of examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) in C, including one that copies a URL to a block of memory, [`getinmemory.c`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html)

For C++, the main page of the `curlcpp` binding at https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp shows an example of downloading a URL to a file.

Comment: Like tadman said: "step one ... is finding a suitable library". Depending on your needs/interests/platform, libcurl can be an excellent choice.  PS: Same in Python.  That's why you "import urllib" ;)  You could instead have chosen to "import requests", or "import sockets", among many other Python libraries...

Comment: could you please give a small example?