# Reading from text file online

Tags: c++

So basically what im trying to do is read text from a raw pastebin file (in C++)(pastebin.com/raw/k1XLUS00). The solution i've come up with is to first download the file and then read from the local file however i now need it to directly read from the web file. Preferably without any extra dependencies.

The length of the text is around 1 line so there might even be a better way to get the text like this which is javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/www.bbc.co.uk",
  complete: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
  }
```

});

Thankful for any help

Comment: Why did you tag this with C++?

Comment: @JVApen probably, that's one last part of the question actually read as "and so are there any better ways to do that, maybe in another language, like—".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read text from internet with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508236/how-to-read-text-from-internet-with-c)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't. *Something* needs to make a DNS request, then open a socket, form and send an HTTP Request, manage the HTTP Response, parse the HTTP Response, feed the content body to your calling scope...... You can't make an HTTP client in two lines of code without anything to actually act as an HTTP client. You could cheat by making a system call to `wget` or `curl`, but then that's an extra dependency innit.

Once you've realised you will need dependencies, look at [How to read text from internet with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508236/how-to-read-text-from-internet-with-c).

Comment: "Well, you can't" - sure you *can*. But it'll be a ton of work if you are not prepared to use any additional libraries. You can certainly write the code to make a DNS lookup, a HTTP request etc etc in C++. It is *possible* but stupid and pointless work (and a case of "not invented here" syndrome) - one should just use existing libraries for that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: At the very least you need access to a socket library (e.g. that found in POSIX).

Comment: just being silly and pedantic here; even that socket library and *even* the underlying OS you *could* write yourself in C++ if you *really* wanted to. ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Okay it is true that you could implement the sockets side of things, but _only_ if you were also implementing the OS. Otherwise you have no access to the required network interface.